# Can class name be excluded from Lombok @ToString?

Tags: java, lombok

[Project Lombok's](https://projectlombok.org/index.html) class annotation, `@ToString`, is used to automatically generate a `toString()` method within the class it annotates.

For this class:

```
@ToString
public class SomeClass {
  String field1="Field #1";
  String field2="Field #2";
}
```

Invoking the generated `toString()` method will produce this output:

`SomeClass(field1="Field #1", field2="Field #2")`

Optional elements of the annotation can be used to include or exclude specific fields, but what I want to know is...

#### "Is there way to tell Lombok to exclude the class name from the output?"

Maybe something like:

```
@ToString(exclude="#classname")
public class SomeClass { ... }
```

Comment: Well, maybe some Lombok maintainer will see this and be inspired

Comment: @Scrubble You might want to create a feature request on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues) if you really want this idea to be seen.

Comment: I believe the reason why Lombok doesn't have this is because the `@ToString` annotation is designed for debugging purposes. The idea is to quickly add the annotation so that an object can be simply printed and its state understood. More explicit formatting implies that one wants to have perhaps a production `toString` method, in which case, you should implement it yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. The [`@ToString`](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/ToString.java) annotation does not have any option that would let you do that.

Comment: This is shocking. _**Shocking**_, I say!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, lombok does not support this. The umbrella feature request for toString formatting improvements can be found here:

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1297